# FLVPlayback - replay counter

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback

Is there a way to output in the text filed a number of how many times the video looped? (how many times it has played)

Thanks, Yan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flex 4 example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

< s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

```
        [Bindable]
        public var looped:Number=0;

        protected function videoplayer1_completeHandler(event:TimeEvent):void
        {
            looped++;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:VideoPlayer loop="true" complete="videoplayer1_completeHandler(event)" source="http://localhost/movie.flv"/>
<s:Label text="{looped}"/>
```

Comment: I get error on the page "protected function videoplayer1_completeHandler(event:TimeEvent):void"

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TimeEvent.

Comment: updated, if you'll get again this error, put your cursor at the end of TimeEvent and press Ctrl+Space

Comment: forgot to import - import org.osmf.events.TimeEvent;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the events dispatched by the FLVPlayback class to increment the number of times played , then that value can be converted to a String for output in a TextField. You will need some form of PHP script if you need to retain that value though.

Comment: I agree.  you can listen for VideoEvent.COMPLETE to determine when the video has reached the end, then increment your counter by 1.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/VideoEvent.html